# Why should I protect self-assigned certificate with asymmetric/symmetric keys?

Tags: sql-server

I'm absolutely new to topics like data encryption/decryption with MS SQL Server.

I have no problem with data encryption/decryption, but I cannot understand why the following example is given as a 'best practice'? Why should I protect the symmetric key with certificate if I can encrypt/decrypt data directly with symmetric key?

```sql
USE SOMEDB
GO

CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = '***';  
GO  

CREATE CERTIFICATE [some_cert] WITH SUBJECT = 'Key Protection';  
GO  

CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY [some_sem_key] WITH  
    KEY_SOURCE = 'My key generation bits. This is a shared secret!',  
    ALGORITHM = AES_256,   
    ENCRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE [some_cert];  
GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer - so that you don't have to share the symmetric key's password in order for those who would use it to encrypt/decrypt to be able to do so.

---

Exposition - what your example code doesn't show is how the key is used. In the case of a symmetric key that is encrypted by a certificate, it's

```sql
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY [some_sem_key] 
   DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE [some_cert];
SELECT EncryptByKey(Key_GUID('some_sem_key'), 'Top Secret');
```

That's on the assumption that the certificate's private key itself is protected via a database master key (which your example shows, but just putting that out there as the certificate's can also be protected via a password which defeats this argument). Access can be controlled via [GRANT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-certificate-permissions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)'ing or revoking permissions on the certificate. Further, if the certificate is somehow compromised, rotating the protection is as easy as:

```sql
create certificate [some_cert2] WITH SUBJECT = 'Key Protection';
go
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY [some_sem_key]
    decryption by certificate [some_cert];
ALTER SYMMETRIC KEY [some_sem_key]
    add encryption by certificate [some_cert2];
ALTER SYMMETRIC KEY [some_sem_key]
    drop encryption by certificate [some_cert];
```

Contrast that with the method necessary if the symmetric key is protected via a password:

```sql
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY [some_sem_key] 
   DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'Sup3rSecurePassword!!!';
SELECT EncryptByKey(Key_GUID('some_sem_key'), 'Top Secret');
```

In that usage, you'd have to put disseminate `Sup3rSecurePassword!!!` everywhere it needs to be used (i.e. applications, individuals who have need to use, etc).

Credential rotation is mostly the same:

```
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY [some_sem_key]
    decryption by password = 'Sup3rSecurePassword!!!'
ALTER SYMMETRIC KEY [some_sem_key]
    add encryption by password = 'M0r3SecurePassword!!!'
ALTER SYMMETRIC KEY [some_sem_key]
    drop encryption by password = 'Sup3rSecurePassword!!!'
```

But the access control story is not. Possession of the password is the only thing controlling access to secrets protected with that symmetric key.

Comment: Hello Ben, thank you for the explanation I am looking for. So idea is to to protect credentials via MS SQL Server user access to ABILITY to operate with the certificate and symmetric key. And thanks to that design I can provide the code to the third party apps (like Pentaho) without credentials. If the user has the RIGHT to encrypt, the code will be processed. Am I right?

Comment: That sounds like a reasonable interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

Your symmetric key is used because it's a lot faster and more resource-efficient than an asymmetric key for encrypting your data.
That means you can get away with the (relatively negligible) overhead of encrypting data with it "in real time".
Encrypting with a symmetric key uses less CPU and produces smaller encrypted data so it uses less storage.
However, it's still a single key.
To mitigate the inherent security risks of leaking a single master key, it's secured using a slower but far more secure certificate.

In short: the certificate protects the key(s) that is (are) used to encrypt the data.

Comment: Hello Wim, I understand that certificate is a container for storing asymmetric key and meta data and it is more secure than symmetric key. I also understand that encryption with symmetric key is much faster (in my case up to 10 times). I do not understand, why can't I avoid the certificate in between, OR why I should use it.  Could you please explain which 'inherent security risks' I avoid with certificate. I can't just copy paste the code, I need to understand why I use such a recipe.

Comment: Or you mean, that I can avoid certificate + symmetric key if I go with asymmetric key?

Comment: @Dimash I think Ben Thul answers all of that more clearly than I could.